# SQL Server Month Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server newbie

The following query returns SRA by Student and month only if there is a record for a student in Discipline table. I need a query to return all students and month totals even if there is no record for student in Discipline table. Any direction appreciated

```
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT MONTH(dbo.Discipline.DisciplineDate) AS [Month], dbo.Discipline.StuId, dbo.Stu.Lastname + ',' + dbo.Stu.FirstName AS Student, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Discipline.SRA = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [Acad Suspension], SUM(CASE WHEN Discipline.SRA = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Conduct, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Discipline.SRA = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Disrespect, SUM(CASE WHEN Discipline.SRA = 4 THEN 1 END) AS [S.R.A], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Discipline.SRA = 5 THEN 1 END) AS Suspension, SUM(CASE WHEN Discipline.SRA = 6 THEN 1 END) AS Tone
FROM dbo.Discipline INNER JOIN
     dbo.Stu ON dbo.Discipline.StuId = dbo.Stu.StuId
GROUP BY dbo.Discipline.StuId, dbo.Stu.Lastname, dbo.Stu.FirstName, MONTH(dbo.Discipline.DisciplineDate)
ORDER BY Student
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `INNER JOIN` onto `dbo.Stu` to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
   SELECT MONTH(d.disciplinedate) AS [Month], 
          d.StuId, 
          s.Lastname + ',' + s.FirstName AS Student, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN d.SRA = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [Acad Suspension], 
          SUM(CASE WHEN d.SRA = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Conduct, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN d.SRA = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Disrespect, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN d.SRA = 4 THEN 1 END) AS [S.R.A], 
          SUM(CASE WHEN d.SRA = 5 THEN 1 END) AS Suspension, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN d.SRA = 6 THEN 1 END) AS Tone
     FROM dbo.Discipline d
LEFT JOIN dbo.Stu s ON s.stuid = d.stuid
 GROUP BY d.StuId, s.Lastname, s.FirstName, MONTH(d.DisciplineDate)
 ORDER BY Student
```

The LEFT JOIN means that whatever table you're LEFT JOINing to might not have records to support the JOIN, but you'll still get records from the base table (dbo.Discipline).

I used table aliases - `d` and `s`.  Less to type when you need to specify references.

Comment: OK  Now I am getting a record for all students. Thank you for your help and pointers. This site is great

Answer (score 0):

generate a series of months, join discipline to that.